# Is there a way to avoid managing selected Puppet resource properties?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, puppet

**The Problem:**
I'm trying to have Puppet manage some of the details of several scheduled tasks without managing whether those tasks are enabled.  To that end, I declare `scheduled_task` resources without any explicit `enabled` attributes, with the intention of communicating that whether the tasks are enabled is not to be altered by Puppet.  Puppet, however, is persistent in re-enabling the tasks on every run, just as if I had specified `enabled => true` for each of them.  How can I make it stop doing that?

**Already Tried:**
I've considered setting the attributes for each datacenter via hiera, but the reality is that this makes failovers and switches more complicated than necessary. I don't want to change my puppet code every time that needs to happen. I also can't shut-off the puppet-agent runs. I need to maintain the integrity of our rolling deployment system.

**Providers?**
I've read a little about providers, seems like I can handle the behavior there. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out where there is (if any) documentation that explains how to use them to override specific resource properties.

**Notify/Subscribe:**
I've thought about using notify/subscribe to only set the triggers to enabled on creation. I'm not thinking this is the right solution, because it's not one resource subscribing to/notifying another, it's properties being set on a single resource. If there's some magical way of doing this or something similar, I'd love to know.

**Bottom-line:** I just need puppet to create disabled tasks, and let me turn them on/off without changing the state in subsequent runs.

Comment: FWIW, I feel this warrants raising a ticket with Puppet. The `enabled` attribute is a *property*, so Puppet will always sync managed systems to its value. It can be argued that properties should *never* take default values, for the reasons you outline here. It's generally useful to be able to manage resources but omit certain properties. Additionally, it is very easy for the user to define their own defaults using *resource defaults* (see John's answer below).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to ignore resource attribute defaults in Puppet entirely?

Only by explicitly declaring a value for every attribute of every resource.

But that doesn't seem to be the question you really wanted to ask.  You seem to be exploring ways to assign attribute values without specifying them as literals in your resource declarations, and I guess you're looking for some kind of layered approach, with the bottom layer replacing or overriding types' and providers' built-in defaults.

As you thought, you could conceivably do this at least in part via providers.  You would need to write a custom provider for your resource type and specify that it be used by each resource instance.  But don't.  This way is complicated to implement and confusing to anyone who later has to read your manifests (maybe including future you).

Notify / subscribe, on the other hand, are simply the wrong tools for the job.  They do not do what you seem to think they do, or perhaps you just haven't thought that idea through.

I think you're selling Hiera short and / or inappropriately minimizing the complexity of the task.  Probably a mixture of both -- I'm inclined to guess that Hiera can do more for you than you appreciate, but also that the complications you envision will manifest to some extent, in some form, no matter what you do.

Nevertheless, there is an approach that seems to match pretty closely what I think you want: [resource default declarations](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/5.1/lang_defaults.html) (I link to the latest docs, but this feature is present, in substantially the same form, in every Puppet version released in at least the last nine years).  Thus, you might cause all `scheduled_task` resources to be disabled unless you explicitly say otherwise by putting this resource default declaration at an appropriate place:

```
Scheduled_task {
  enabled => false
}
```

When choosing where to put such a statement, do note that, unlike anything else in modern Puppet, resource default statements have dynamic scope.  The manual discusses that in somewhat more detail.

---

**Revisited:**

In light of the clarification of the question, I'll clarify that resource types' providers are where resource management behavior lives.  Therefore, if Puppet's behavior on target machines is not what you want in the event of an altogether missing property declaration, then modifying the provider or writing your own are pretty much your only alternatives.  Of course, if you have a support contract then perhaps you don't have to do that in-house.

If you don't want to hack on providers -- an altogether reasonable position -- then you're left with managing the properties to their desired values.  Supposing that you employ Hiera effectively, however, you should not need to modify any manifests to control which servers have their tasks enabled.

Comment: I'm afraid you may have misunderstood the question. Our servers run puppet agent at half-hour intervals. Setting a default of enabled false would simply shut my scheduled tasks off every half-hour unless they're explicitly set to enabled. That's the problem here, I've got the same task running in two datacenters, and it should only be active in one. I truly need it to just be hands off with enabled/disabled unless I explicitly set them. To set enabled/disabled per datacenter via hiera would make failovers a puppet-coding nightmare. Don't want that.

Comment: @Joe.Flanigan, yes, I did misunderstand the question.  I have edited it to be clearer (at least to me).

Comment: John, I really appreciate the time you've taken to work with me on the question. The way we have Hiera deployed would work great until a failover, then we'd have to change all the values. Though I never say never, I don't foresee any easy route (given our current setup) to a resolution via Hiera. To provide some resolution here: starting with puppet's win32_taskscheduler, I wrote my own type and provider and customized everything to work the way I wanted. Painful, but it provides even greater flexibility in the end.